# Fit FlowPane into ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I using this code to fir FlowPane into ScrollPane

```
FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
scroll.setContent(flowPane);
scroll.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> ov, Bounds oldBounds, Bounds bounds)
    {
        flowPane.setPrefWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        flowPane.setPrefHeight(bounds.getHeight());
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this maybe is not the best solution. Is there another more simple way to fit FlowPane into ScrollPane in Java 8?

Answer (score 10):

There are methods of ScrollPane meant to do this:

```
scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `maxWidth` and `maxHeoght` properties of your flowPane to `Double.MAX_VALUE` either via CSS or via API so as to provide its maximal expansion whithin container:

```
flowPane.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: For some reason it's not working properly. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Maybe set prefSize also to the MAX_VALUE?